# Perform a 'task' via an enum and a field, by checking the 'T' type, and inferring it into the task automatically

Tags: c#, reflection, automation, game-development

I've come across an issue that I cannot solve. I've got an `IReadOnlyList` of classes that each have a bunch of fields. These fields have names (variable names) identical to a list of enums. Think that for each field that exists, an enum for it with the exact same name also exists (so `object helloHi` has an equivalent `enum something { helloHi }`).

What I've attempted to do is compare the two field names. If they are identical, perform a function on them. The problem is that the function needs to infer a `T` from the variable, and since reflection isn't able to pull that 'T' without some form of cast, it won't proceed.

This is the code:

```
public class Something() {

    [BackgroundTask]
    private void load(Overlay param_1, Config param_2) {
        Children = new Drawable[] // is the IReadOnlyList
        {
            SomethingClass(param_1),
            AnotherClass(param_2)
        }

        performTask(this, param_2);
    }
}

public class Config {

    public void task<U>(SomeEnums se, ValueType<U> value) // do the task
}

public class SomethingClass {

    ValueType<double> someDouble = new ValueType<double>();
    ValueType<int> someInt = new ValueType<int>();

    public SomethingClass(Overlay overlay) //...
}

public enum SomeEnums {
    someDouble,
    someInt,
}

void performTask(Something the_class, Config the_config) {
    // ... for each field within the_class, do (uses reflection)
    field => {
        foreach (SomeEnums enums in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnums)))
        {
            if (field.Name == enums.ToString()) {
                the_config.task(enums, field.GetValue(null)); // cant infer 'U' from an 'object'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Technically, I could just do the `config.task` within the class where the types are known and visible, but I'd much prefer to automate it from here, so that it doesn't need 2-3 changes every time a new variable is created.

One of the strategies I am aware of is performing an `if` check within the `performTask` like such:

```
// performTask, field =>, foreach
{
    if (field.FieldType == ValueType<double>)
        config.task(enums, (ValueType<double>)field.GetValue(null));
} //etc
```

However, I don't like this method. It would just need to introduce more and more checks if I ever created more `ValueType<>` and if they aren't already being checked for. Would there be a better way to perform what I want?

Comment: What's an "IReadOnlyList of classes"? Do you mean class names, `Type` instances, or do you mean "IReadOnlyList of objects of various classes"?  Things named "class" aren't collectible.  If the types of your fields implement `IComparable` (the non-generic version), then you should be do this pretty simply using reflection with a cast to IComparable once you fish out the field.  However, between your writeup and your code, I can't quite tell what you are trying to do (for example, what does `Children = new Drawable[] // is the IReadOnlyList` mean?).

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. `Children` is a `IReadOnlyList<Drawable>`. The list is supposed to contain instansiated classes, yes, given `new SomethingClass`.

Comment: Your question has `Children` as an array of `Drawable`.  Your `SomethingClass` isn't declared to be a `Drawable`. Your `AnotherClass` isn't declared at all.  You say you want to "compare the two field names. If they are identical, perform a function on them".  Are the "two field names" identically named fields in two different objects?  If so, what do you do if  `Children` has more than two elements.  Did my Answer (which I realize doesn't answer your question) point you in the correct direction?

Comment: I'm going to assume OP didn't remember to write the code. Probably was in a rush.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, I can't quite tell what you really want to do.  However, here's some code that should help you figure it out.

It uses reflection to get the fields of objects, look at the names of those fields (comparing them to the values/names associated with an `enum` type) and compare the values.  I do a comparison to integer 5, but you could compare to anything (but, it appears that the integer type's implementation of IComparable.CompareTo throws if it's compared to something other than an `int`, so I check).  Since you know the type of everything, this is easy to check (you don't have to compare to a fixed `Type`, you can use what is returned by `GetType()`).

I started with some auxiliary types:

```
public enum SomeEnums {
    SomeDouble,
    SomeInt,
}

public class Class1 {
    public int SomeInt = 5;
    public double SomeDouble = 3.14;
}

public class Class2 {
    public int SomeInt = 5;
    public double SomeDouble = 6.28;
}
```

and then added this:

```
public class EnumFields {

    public List<object> Objects = new List<object> {
        new Class1(),
        new Class2(),
    };

    public void PerformTask () {
        var enumVals = Enum.GetNames(typeof(SomeEnums));
        foreach (var obj in Objects) {
            var objType = obj.GetType();
            var fieldInfos = objType.GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);
            //right around here I get lost.  You have a list of objects (which has two instances right now), 
            //What are you comparing, that every field named SomeInt has the same value??
            //Anyway, here's some code that should help you
            foreach (var fieldInfo in fieldInfos) {
                if (enumVals.Contains(fieldInfo.Name)) {
                    var fieldObj = fieldInfo.GetValue(obj);
                    var isSame = false;
                    if (fieldObj.GetType() == typeof(int)) {
                        var comparable = (IComparable)fieldObj;
                        var same = comparable.CompareTo(5);
                        isSame = (same == 0);
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Field: {fieldInfo.Name} of instance of {obj.GetType().Name} (Value: {fieldObj}) is equal to 5:{isSame}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I instantiate an `EnumFields` object and call `PerformTask` on it, I see this in the output:

```
Field: SomeInt of instance of Class1 (Value: 5) is equal to 5:True
Field: SomeDouble of instance of Class1 (Value: 3.14) is equal to 5:False
Field: SomeInt of instance of Class2 (Value: 5) is equal to 5:True
Field: SomeDouble of instance of Class2 (Value: 6.28) is equal to 5:False
```

This should get you most of the way there.  I realize it doesn't answer your question.  Had I been able to figure out what you were asking, it probably would have.